# How to write a struct to a file C

Tags: c, file-io

Is it possible to write the data in my `struct` to a text file?

Below is my `struct`:

```
struct Person{
    int date;
    char acName[30];
    int Weight;
    float Length;
    float Quetelet;
};
```

Below is how I tried to write it to the file:

```
FILE *fptr;
fptr = fopen ("hello.txt", "w");
if (fptr == NULL){
  printf ("Error!");
  exit (1);
}
fprintf (fptr, "Date: %d\n", p.date);
fprintf (fptr, "Name: %s\n", p.acName);
fprintf (fptr, "Weight: %d\n", p.Weight);
fprintf (fptr, "Length: %f\n", p.Length);
fprintf (fptr, "Your Quetelet: f", &p.Quetelet);

fclose (fptr);
```

But when I try that, I get the following output:

```
Date: 4201600
Name: Ðþ(
Weight: 4201600
Length: 0.000000
Your Quetelet: 0.000000
```

Comment: Yes it is possible.  If you had a problem then you should state what that problem is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Putting aside the obvious question of what a `quetelet` actually *is,* I believe you shouldn't be trying to write the address of it, *especially* without a valid format specifier:

```
fprintf(fptr,"Your Quetelet: f",&p.Quetelet);
```

Instead, give this a shot:

```
fprintf(fptr,"Your Quetelet: %f",p.Quetelet);
```

If the printing is actually *working* but you seem to be getting strange values, make sure you're *setting* the variables to something before ou attempt to print them.

Comment: if i try fprintf(fptr,"Your Quetelet: %f",p.Quetelet);

i get the following output:

Date: 4201600
Name: Ðþ(
Weight: 4201600
Length: 0.000000
Your Quetelet: 0.000000

Comment: @dutch: yes, and the problem with that is what exactly? If you're seeing 0, it's likely that p.Quetelet is zero. And it's likely that your name is uninitialised.

Comment: i allready see whats happening, everything was 0 cause the write function went before the other variables could be set. And Quetelet is like the same as BMI index ;) ty